# Callable php, reference to the function or value

Tags: php, function

I'm getting a bit of confusion about the Callable type in php, I'm not sure if a variable assigned to a callback function gets the value returned by the function or whether it gets a reference of the function.

```
function ($x){
   return x;
}

function func1(callable $func){
   $var = $func;
}
```

and It's possible to do

```
$var($a)
```

Comment: It gets the function, you have to use `()` to call the function and return a value.

Comment: It's just like any other value. Assigning it to a variable just copies a reference.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is neither. When you specify a callable type you say that you will call this variable. It can be in a form of a string or array or closure. Whatever the value of this variable is you are telling PHP that you intend to execute it.

```
// Type 1: Simple callback
func1('my_callback_function');

// Type 2: closure
func1(fn()=>'returnvalue');

// Type 3: Object method call
$obj = new MyClass();
func1([$obj, 'myCallbackMethod']);
```

For more information see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php